# ui style for selected item in angularjs material

Tags: angularjs, material-design, angular-material

On my UI, I have several buttons. I want to highlight those user have tapped for few seconds. Is there any directive or style I can use? Or I have to write my own?

Comment: [http://augus.github.io/ngAnimate/](http://augus.github.io/ngAnimate/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, what you are asking for is already available in angular-material.
Just make sure you are making your buttons as below:

```
    <md-button class="md-raised md-primary">Zero</md-button>
```

Here `md-button` is the directive and the class you specify will change the look and feel... say `md-primary`, `md-fab`...

[Angular materials documentation here](https://material.angularjs.org/latest/demo/button)

`md-select` is there in angular-material. You can always group together buttons if you want, place them in an `md-list` and they will behave as you want. And, yes, `md-menu` & `md-dropdown` are coming in next few releases.

Comment: Thanks, @Alon nitin, I've read that document. And what I'm asking is something similar to md-select in md-tabs. I know I can walk around by changing colors, etc. I want to learn from experts what is the recommended way of doing this task. It seems to me that button by nature  is not grouped together, that is why angular-material does not provide a md-select. md-tabs does. Please correct me if I'm wrong. Appreciate your time!

Comment: md-select is there in angular-material. You can always group together buttons if you want, place them in an md-list and they will behave as u want.   And yes md-menu & md-dropdown is coming in next few releases.

Comment: That is what I need. Thanks! Could you please put this comment into the answer? I appreciate your help!